# Unable to Log WebSocket Messages in Python Flask Application for Twilio Media Streaming

Tags: python, flask, websocket, twilio

I am currently working on a Python Flask application to integrate with Twilio for media streaming during phone calls. The goal is to use WebSocket to handle messages sent from Twilio when a call starts streaming. While the WebSocket connection to localhost:8080 is working perfectly, I am facing an issue with logging the incoming WebSocket messages.

The code I am using is based on the Twilio JavaScript tutorial, which logs various message events like "connected," "start," "media," and "stop." However, after translating the JavaScript code to Python, the expected logging does not seem to occur.

Here is my Python code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import os
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def root():
    # ... TwiML response handling ...

async def handle_websocket(websocket, path):
    print("New Connection Initiated")
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            print(f"Received message: {message}")
            # Add your WebSocket message handling logic here
            # You can use the 'message' variable to parse the incoming JSON message from Twilio
            msg = json.loads(message)
            event = msg.get('event')
            if event == 'connected':
                print('A new call has connected.')
            elif event == 'start':
                print(f"Starting Media Stream {msg.get('streamSid')}")
            elif event == 'media':
                print("Receiving Audio...")
            elif event == 'stop':
                print('Call Has Ended')
            # For now, let's just echo the message back to the client
            await websocket.send(message)
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
        print("WebSocket connection closed.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server = websockets.serve(handle_websocket, "0.0.0.0", 8080)
    print("Listening at Port 8080")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

When running this code, the WebSocket connection is successfully established, and the "New Connection Initiated" message is printed. However, the server does not seem to receive the expected message events ("connected," "start," "media," and "stop") from Twilio, and thus, the logging does not occur as intended.

I suspect there might be an issue with how the WebSocket messages are being parsed or a potential discrepancy between the Python and JavaScript logic for WebSocket handling. I have reviewed the code multiple times but have not been able to identify the root cause of this issue.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or possible solutions to troubleshoot and resolve this problem. Thank you!